# Switch Master and Slave role in mysql

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

```
Mysql Server1 is running as MASTER.  -- server id =1
Mysql Server2 is running as SLAVE.  -- server id =2
```

Now DB replication is happening from MASTER to SLAVE.

`Switch:`

Now when I stop Slave on Server2 and Configure Server1 as Slave (by command CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=') and start Slave on server1, the replication failed with below error:

```
Last_IO_Errno: 1593
Last_IO_Error: Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because master and slave have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on slave but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it).
```

Im using MYSQL

Pls help as im new to MYSQL.